# Discriminating integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

Given a fixed positive integer, say $n$, letn $P_n$ be the set all partitions of $n$, where each partition itself is a set i.e. order is discarded and each part is less than 5. Can we establish a bijective mapping $f:P_n \to [1, |Pn|]$ such that for a partition $x$, $f(x)$ is computable without explicitly using $P_n$ (otherwise, we would lexicographically order them and establish the bijection.). Rather, I want $f$ to be computable only from the parts of the partition. My interest is in discriminating differnt partition. If this is not possible, I would look for $f$ which is injective, and co-domain is not necessary to be as defined as above, but preferably have cardinality not very large compared to $|P_n|$. It is fine even if this conditions are met for $n < 30$, though general function would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you surely know the number of partitions with all parts less than $k$ is the same as the number of partitions into less than $k$ parts - simple conjugation of partition's Young diagram gives you the bijection. So your set $P_n$ would be equal to $P_n^1\cup P_n^2\cup P_n^3\cup P_n^4$ where $P_n^k$ is the set of all partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts.

We know that $|P_n^1| = 1$, $|P_n^2| = \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1$, $|P_n^3| = $round($\frac{(n+3)^2}{12}$) (see *Hardy, G.H. Some Famous Problems of the Theory of Numbers. Clarendon Press, 1920*) - which is pretty easy to prove. Therefore we only need to index each set $P_n^k$ in your union.

Indexing $P_n^1$ and $P_n^2$ is obvious. It is tougher to do for $P_n^3$ and especially $P_n^4$... but I think it is doable. Hope this helps.